# Does it follow that hot air is always replaced by cold air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, density, air

A cylinder contains a powder made up two substances - spherical grains of metal and spherical grains of plastic. In between the grains are voids, so that the cylinder is made up of 75% powder grains and 25% air. The cylinder is oriented vertically. It is sealed at the bottom and open at the top.

The cylinder is heated, and the plastic grains start to melt. The air in the voids gets less dense as the temperature increases, and rises. Some of the hot air leaves the cylinder, but some of the air gets trapped in the melting plastic, and forms small pockets of air encased in the now melted plastic.

Would heating the cylinder slowly allow for more of the air to leave the voids before the plastic is melted? Or, would this rising air just be replaced by falling cooler air that fills the voids?

Answer (score 1):

> If we want to minimize the pockets of air that get trapped, what can we do?

Step 1: Draw a vacuum.*

Step 2: Heat until all the plastic is for sure, melted.**

Step 3: Wait for plastic to "slump" to the point where, there may still be some voids, but they aren't big enough to be connected to each other.***

Step 4: Return to normal pressure.

---

* Eliminate the whole question of hot air/cool air/trapped air by eliminating the air.

** This might not be as easy as it sounds, because when there's no air touching the spheres, then the only way for heat to reach them is by conduction and radiation from their neighbors. Conduction is a problem because, as the wise man once said, "two spheres touch very little." Radiation could be a problem because the surfaces might not be very emissive. Maybe you could pre-heat it to almost-but-not-quite melting with hot air before you draw the vacuum, and then finish heating *slooooowly* by applying heat to the walls of the container.

*** If you *really* want to get fancy, then a centrifuge might help at this stage of the process.